# Input not firing in jsp page

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i have been using the spring mvc frameworks lately for a university project. Could you tell me why this work

```
 <FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="SaveName.jsp">
     <input type="image" class="floatR marginTMinus10" 
             src="images/delete.png" name="image" 
             value="${rssItem.id}" alt="Delete"/>
 </FORM>
```

while this not

```
<input type="image" class="floatR marginTMinus10"
        src="images/delete.png" name="image" value="${rssItem.id}" alt="Delete"/>
```

does it mean a button has to be in a form to work?

Can i use a button? if yes how do i handle the event in the controller?

thanks

Comment: This doesn't have to do with spring only, but rather with html. I'm retagging,

Comment: Regardless, if you'd like to have a button with a background image, then rather don't use `input type="image"`, but a normal `input type="submit"` with a CSS `background-image`. The `input type="image"` is intented to be used as an image map, because it sends the `x` and `y` positions as request parameters instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type="image"` defines the button as a *submit* button. And a submit button *needs* a form to submit.

As of how to use buttons to trigger spring actions - I've done it like that: `document.location='someController.do?action=save&otherparam=other';`.

As a side-note - be consistent in your HTML - either use uppercase or lowercase for tags. Always add quotations around attributes (`METHOD="POST"`)